# jquery multiple ids same function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a table that has a date input

```
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker0"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker1"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker2"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker3"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker4"></td>
```

I am trying to access it via for the first one

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker0" ).datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

How do I access everything?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could use the "[attribute starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[id^='datepicker']").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```

That selector will match any `input` element whose `id` value starts with "datepicker". An alternative would be to give all the required elements a common class.

You can also select multiple elements by `id` using a comma-separated list:

```
$("#datepicker0, #datepicker1, #datepicker2"); //List as many as necessary
```

But that's not particularly scalable if you ever need to add more inputs.

Answer (score 13):

The best way is to use a class:

```
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" class="dp" id="datepicker0"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" class="dp" id="datepicker1"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" class="dp" id="datepicker2"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" class="dp" id="datepicker3"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" class="dp" id="datepicker4"></td>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".dp" ).each(function(){
            $(this).datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

but you can also use this:

```
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker0"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker1"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker2"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker3"></td>
<td style="background-color:#c6efce"><input type="text" id="datepicker4"></td>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker0,#datepicker1,#datepicker2,#datepicker3,#datepicker4" ).datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

The second approach is not advised.

Comment: Why did you use an each function in the first example, instead of calling datepicker on the node list like the second one?

Comment: @mikerobi lol good point XD perhaps you can submit an answer as such?

Comment: Thank you @JosephMarikle

Answer (score 10):

As I understand your question, you're trying to select multiple IDs using jQuery. Here's how you do that:

```
$('#1,#2,#3')
```

You just separate the IDs by commas.

But, this isn't the best way to accomplish this. You should really use a class: Assign each `td` a class and use:

```
$('td.myClass')
```

Alternatively, you could assign an ID to the table and select all of its `td` children. HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('table#myTable td')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this as well
`$('#datepicker0,#datepicker1,#datepicker2,#datepicker3,#datepicker4)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IDs, you should use a CSS class named something like `has-datepicker` and search for that.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI automatically adds the "hasDatePicker" class to all elements that have a date picker. You can query the page for something like $("input.hasDatePicker") to get all of the date pickers.

Comment: Not before the `datepicker` has been applied to the element (as in this case...)

Comment: Ah, I read the original question wrong, thought the original question asked about accessing them, not creating them, but I guess the OP did provide a code snippet where he showed he was creating one...